# Unable to change "Shop" category name in menu?

Tags: magento2

this should be an easy one -- my changes to the default "Shop" category name aren't reflected on the nav on the frontend despite lots of cache-clearing, etc. Anything should try / look into?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure what that would accomplish, sorry.

Comment: Can you check if its changed under store view if you have multi stores?

Comment: Do you want me add an answer?

Comment: Go for it, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to change the category name from default view then might be you have a multiple stores.

Goto different store view and try to change the category name then flush the cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to reindex after changing the category name to get everything updated.

Command line:
php bin\magento indexer:reindex

This will solve issue if store is correct.